# How do I bind an uploaded image file to an ASP.NET MVC 5 model using Kendo for jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've ready everything I can find on this topic, but nothing has solved my issue. I'm completely new to Kendo (and it's version 2018.1.221, which is old), relatively new to ASP.NET MVC 5, and my jQuery skills are very rusty.

I have a Kendo grid, populated by a dashboard model. Each row has an Edit button. I have added a new column to upload an image, but the image field in my controller is null when I save. I'm trying to save the image itself to my database, not just the URL.

admin.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var dashboardData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autosync: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: APP_PATH + 'BIAdmin/DashboardList',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
        update: {
            url: APP_PATH + 'BIAdmin/UpdateDashboard',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
        create: {
            url: APP_PATH + 'BIAdmin/CreateDashboard',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: APP_PATH + 'BIAdmin/DestroyDashboard',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            switch (operation) {
                case "read":
                    return {
                    };
                case "update":
                    return {
                        Dashboard: {
                            DashboardKey: options["DashboardKey"],                               
                            DashboardName: options["DashboardName"],                              
                            ThumbnailImage: options["ThumbnailImage"],                     
                        }
                    };
                case "create":
                    return {
                        Dashboard: {
                            DashboardKey: options["DashboardKey"],                              
                            DashboardName: options["DashboardName"],                              
                            ThumbnailImage: options["ThumbnailImage"],                              
                        }
                    };
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "DashboardKey",
            expanded: false,
            fields:
            {
                DashboardKey: { type: "number", editable: false },                  
                DashboardName: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },                  
                ThumbnailImage: { type: "byte", editable: true, validation: { required: false } },                  
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 20
});

$("#DashboardGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dashboardData,
    dataBound: function (e) {
        $("input[type='file']").kendoUpload();
        async: {
            saveUrl: '~/Controllers/BIAdmin/UpdateImage'  
            autoUpload: true;
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns:
        [
            {
                field: "DashboardKey", title: "Key", template: "#=DashboardKey#", width: "80px",
                filterable: { operator: "equals" }
            },              
            {
                field: "DashboardName", title: "Dashboard", width: "300px",
                filterable: { operator: "contains" }
            },              
            {
                field: "ThumbnailImage", title: "Thumbnail Image", editor: thumbnailEditor, width: "300px",
                filterable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }
        ]      
});

function thumbnailEditor(container, options) {
    $('<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input id="ThumbnailImage" type="file" data-role="upload" name="ThumbnailImage" /></form> ')
        .appendTo(container)
}});
```

BIAdminController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateImage(DashboardImage dashboard, HttpPostedFileBase ThumbnailImage)
{
        try
        {
            Debugger.Break();  <--This never gets hit
            DashboardImage d = db.DashboardImage.Find(dashboard.ThumbnailImage);

            if (ThumbnailImage != null)
            {
                d.ImageName = "FakeImageName";
                d.ThumbnailImage = new byte[ThumbnailImage.ContentLength];
                ThumbnailImage.InputStream.Read(d.ThumbnailImage, 0, ThumbnailImage.ContentLength);
            }

            db.DashboardImage.Add(dashboard);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(dashboard);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", e.Message);
            return Json(null);
        }
}
   
public JsonResult UpdateDashboard(DashboardModel dashboard)
{
        try
        {
            Dashboard d = db.Dashboard.Find(dashboard.DashboardKey);
            d.DashboardName = dashboard.DashboardName ?? " ";
            DashboardImage di = new DashboardImage();
            di.DashboardKey = dashboard.DashboardKey; <---This is always null             
            db.SaveChanges();
            
            dashboard.ThumbnailImage = db.DashboardImage.Where(x => x.DashboardKey == dashboard.DashboardKey)
                .Select(x => x.ThumbnailImage).FirstOrDefault();
            
            return Json(dashboard);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", e.Message);
            return Json(null);
        }
}
```

DashboardModel.cs:

```
public class DashboardModel
{
    public int DashboardKey { get; set; }        
    public string DashboardName { get; set; }        
    public byte[] ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
}
```

DashboardImageModel:

```
public class DashboardImageModel
{
    public int ImageKey { get; set; }
    public int DashboardKey { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    public virtual Dashboard Dashboard { get; set; }
}
```